# Does Spring Security 5.7.2 support OpenJDK 17.x?

Tags: spring-security, java-17

We are planning to migrate our application from OpenJDK from 11.x to 17.x.

Currently we are using Spring Security 5.7.2.

Does Spring Security 5.7.2 support OpenJDK 17.x ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it supports Java 8 *or higher*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.2/prerequisites.html).

I wasn’t able to find the specific version in which it became officially supported, but anyway the road to Spring 6 & Spring Security 6 requires to upgrade to Java 17 first.

Note that they recommend [upgrading to Spring Security 5.8](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/index.html) before switching to 6.